# Why is '&regDataType' rendered as '®DataType' in a <pre> block?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947865/10120575).

**My Browser**: Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**BUG**: (in his code)

```
    regPropSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &devInfoData, 
    SPDRP_DEVICEDESC, ®DataType, 
    (PBYTE)deviceDesc, sizeof(deviceDesc), &reqSize);
```

**Detail**: in the HTML resource code, the original code is `&regDataType`, but somehow it is incorrectly represented as an HTML character entity `®DataType` in the end.

Is this a bug of Stack Overflow, or just a historical issue, considering that it is an eight year old question?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532252/why-is-reg-being-rendered-as-without-the-bounding-semicolon) and [this](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/HTMLPlus/htmlplus_13.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was (partially) caused by incorrect indentation.

That answer used a `<pre>` block instead of indenting the code. This caused the parser to register the `&reg` part of `&regDataType` as ®

The fact that that did get parsed as an HTML entity does appear to be a **bug**, though, as there's no closing `;`

Meanwhile, I've [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4947865/revisions) the answer. It now renders correctly.

Comment: It's not a bug; it's a feature of most browsers. Which is a bug deliberately programmed in for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: It shouldn't be parsed in code / `<pre>` blocks. I'd argue that this is a feature they shouldn't have built-in, if they even did so deliberately.

Comment: @Stijn Erm... because that's what the standards say? They parse all _sorts_ of HTML!

Comment: @Cerbrus: You can blame pretty much every invalid markup-specific "feature" like this on the thousands if not millions of websites that were written poorly and ended up relying on the behavior.

Answer (score -1):

No. You've actually got a ® character in your question's source. HTML expands `&reg;` to ®, but Stack Overflow disables this for inside code blocks, but not manually-created `<pre>` blocks. Use four spaces or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to avoid this issue.

Comment: There was no `&reg;` in the source code.

Comment: Since when have browsers ever followed the standards correctly? (Actually, I think optional `;` might be part of the standard but whatever.) I can guarantee that a Stack Snippet would work the same way, though. So would a jsfiddle.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: The semicolon is required for the markup to be conforming, [but the missing-semicolon behavior is standardized anyway](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-reference-state) because poorly written websites rely on it.